# Is it okay to use ArrayList<> inside a HashMap when creating an ExpandableListView? Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

in my database adapter i've created an ArrayList where i will call multiple columns to be display in each row of my ExpandableListView. Then created a HashMap where my HashMap looks like this

```
private HashMap<ArrayList<MyModel>, List<String>> mchildOfDetails;
```

My HashMap is used for displaying the Header and Child of the ExpandableListView  the first parameter of my HashMap was for my header and the second one is for the child items for each header.

so my problem was i don't know how will i iterate the variable Details where this Details is the ArrayList value.Because currently if i put it inside a for loop it doesn't show the child item and if i remove the for loop it displays the child but not all the value only one item for each row where it there are only 3 values for child. The first 3 header will only have one value of child.

```
    for(Integer i=0; i>=child.size(); i++){
        hashDataChild.put(Details, child);
}
```

i always found examples where when using hashmap it always use

```
private HashMap<String, List<String>> mchild;
```

so is it possible to use ArrayList instead String only?

MyModel is my model created to be used in my ArrayList, here is my code

```
public class MyModel {

String desc, location;

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
```

}

here is where i used my ArrayList which is inside my DBHelper

```
public ArrayList<MyModel> getDetails(Integer id) {

    Cursor localCursor =
            this.myDataBase.query(TBL_INFO, new String[]{
                            KEY_ID,
                            KEY_DESCRIPTION,
                            KEY_LOCATION
                    },
                    "_id= '" + id + "'",
                    null, null, null, null);

    Details myObj;

    ArrayList<MyModel> listBasedOnID = new ArrayList<MyModel>();

    for (localCursor.moveToFirst(); !(localCursor.isAfterLast()); localCursor.moveToNext()) {
        myObj = new MyModel();
      myObj.setDesc(localCursor.getString(localCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESCRIPTION)));
      myObj.setLocation(localCursor.getString(localCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATION)));


        listBasedOnID.add(myObj);
    }

    localCursor.close();
    return listBasedOnID;
}
```

What i wanted to do is

[image: ExpandableListView]

and when click the child items will show

[image: ChildView]

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to have an ArrayList as key in a HashMap

Comment: couldn't understand the problem you are having inside the for loop.

Comment: @haint what alternative solution can i use instead of using ArrayList?

Comment: To be honest I don't understand your question at all. What is `MyModel` and why do you have to store an array of it as ONE key of a HashMap?

Comment: @NameSpace my problem inside the for loop is that i shoud do something like Details[i] so that in every header i can put my child items on it. But i know i can't do something like that because it is an ArrayList<>

Comment: see this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E) to know how to add an element to a specific position in an `ArrayList`

Comment: I read your edited question, but I still don't know what the value `List<String>` in your hashmap is for. Can you show me a screenshot/sketch of the layout you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: My bad mchildOfDetails must be headerAndChild 
the List<String> is for my child items @haint

Comment: The best answer I can give you right now based on the pictures is that you should store the `ArrayList<MyModel>` as a variable and add an attribute `id` to `MyModel`. This way you can iterate through the HashMap using the `id` as key. If you have this project on github maybe I can help more

Comment: can i have a sample code for it to guide me on how will i apply it? @haint thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82879/discussion-between-haint-and-kairi-san).